# How do I set a Gtk.StatusIcon as Text

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I'd like to create a Gtk.StatusIcon with custom text. Ideally I'd like to append this to an existing image, but text-only is ok, too. How can I achieve this?

I've seen some posts about getting a Gtk.Label's pixbuf but those methods seem to be removed from Gtk3 (pixbuf_get_from_drawable)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible. The status icon is not a widget and the icon is going to be scaled by the window manager. Even if you used `Cairo` or `PIL` to generate an image on the fly to use as the icon pixbuf, it wouldn't have the effect of an embedded label in the system tray. It would instead be tiny, unreadable text smushed into the size of the other icons.